# Linux, MS Teams, pop-ups and focus

Tags: linux, window-focus, microsoft-teams, fluxbox

My organisation uses MS Teams for communication a lot; I'm running it on Ubuntu 18.04, fluxbox as my WM.

I'd like to know whether it's possible to stop team's pop-ups from stealing focus.  It's incredibly annoying when you're trying to `sudo` on a server and in the middle of typing the password your keyboard focus gets stolen (sometimes three, four times in a row).